# Running Xcode build is taking a very long time in flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase

I am using Firebase as a part of my App, after installing  `firebase_core: ^1.22.0` & `cloud_firestore: ^3.4.9` the Running Xcode build is taking between 15 to 20 min. while earlier it was taking 1 to 3 min. only, the same is applicable for physical devices & simulators... I have no issues uploading to Android devices, the uploading time is between 2 to 3 min only, moreover it is slowing the App performance... can anybody help me in this

Comment: Now I have a new error

Comment: 'warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')'

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides Precompiled Firestore iOS SDK xcframework files. Really cuts down on compile times.

You can read more here: https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks#supported-firebase-ios-sdk-versions

and here:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods

Answer (score 0):

Firestore iOS SDK depends on some 500k lines of mostly C++. That's why it takes too much time in build. You need to add this line in `Podfile`:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  #This line. The tag depends on what Firebase SDK you have installed.
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '9.5.0'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

For more information:
https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks

If there is a problem with the deployment target, update platform value to 11.0 or 12.0 in `Podfile`.

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Run `pod install` in `ios` folder to update the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I applied the same as per you reply (the same was advised in the links provided by jbryanh but the following error shows

Comment: ```Specs satisfying the `FirebaseFirestore/AutodetectLeveldb (= 9.6.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.                      Exception: Error running pod install```